# save message archive immediately

Tags: xmpp

I'm using XEP-136 for message archiving in a chat system, when the user types his text, it will be displayed in the chat conversation for both users, and it will be automatically archived for further retrieving.

But when reloading the chat window, and re-connecting to the xmpp server (openfire), the last message won't be shown until one minute or more.

That means, the message won't be fully archived immediately.

Are there any settings in openfire that I must check out first? or do I have to try something other than message archiving?

This is my "retrieve collection" stanza (in strophe.js syntax) :

```
$iq({type: 'get'}).c('retrieve', {xmlns: 'urn:xmpp:archive', with : 'user@server',start:'13-10-28T16:30:00'}).c('set', {xmlns: 'http://jabber.org/protocol/rsm'}).c('max').t('100');
```

So far, The sending and receiving parts work great, the sole issue, is that when reloading page, messages less than 1 minute won't show up until reloading the page after another 1 minute.

it seems that messages take more than 1 minute before being archived.

Comment: Message is 2 years old, but I'm facing the same problem, did u find an answer? :D

Comment: @Niallith hi, sorry I didn't check my stackoverflow account until now, Actually I completely forgot about xmpp hhh, I didn't use it since 2013 ...and of course, I forgot what I did (or whether I solved the problem or not) back then. Sorry